# What model is graphics card

Tags: terminal, drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

**I have no idea what I am doing so bear with me**

I need to update the drivers for my graphics card, and to do that I need the "update file". I don't know what it is actually called but I need to get it from [this](https://www.amd.com/en/support) AMD website. If you scroll down, you can see that you need to select the model of the GPU. I followed the steps on [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-tell-which-graphics-vga-card-installed/) website to get the GPU model name and got this:

```
Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Wani [Radeon R5/R6/R7 Graphics] (rev ca) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

As you can see, it says R5, R6 and R7, so which one is it? What would I type into the AMD website to get the update file?

When running `lspci  -v | grep -A6 VGA` I get:

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Wani [Radeon R5/R6/R7 Graphics] (rev ca) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Carrizo
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 40
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f0800000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=8M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=256]
    Memory at f0500000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
```

Comment: is there a separate download for R5, R6 and R7?

Comment: What is the output from `lspci  -v | grep -A6 VGA`? Can you edit it into the question?

Comment: @icarus I have updated my question.

Comment: @jsotola Yes, and seprate downloads for each of those.

Comment: Thanks, that was less useful than I had hoped. There are more options to lspci, which might help identify the card. `-nn`, `-vv`.  Can you see if `lspci -s 0:1.0 -vv -nn` helps identify it?